# Полное объединение двух таблиц

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть две таблицы t1 и t2. t1 ссылается на t2. Как будет выглядеть запрос, чтобы результатом его была t1 с элементами t2, если в t1 на t2 есть ссылка, а если ссылки нет, то вместо элементов t2 возвращаются null-ы?

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  Id INT IDENTITY
 ,Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
 ,t2_Id INT NULL DEFAULT (NULL)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_t1_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE cfgr2.dbo.t2 (
  Id INT IDENTITY
 ,Val INT NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_t2_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT INTO t1 (Name, t2_Id) VALUES ('N1', 1), ('N2', NULL), ('N3', 2), ('N4', NULL), ('N5', 3), ('N6', 5);
INSERT INTO t2 (Val) VALUES (100), (200), (300), (400), (500);

+--------------------+    +-------------+
| t1                 |    | t2          |
+-----+------+-------+    +-----+-------+
| Id  | Name | t2_Id |    | Id  | Val   | 
+-----+------+-------+    +-----+-------+
| 1   | N1   | 1     |    | 1   | 100   | 
| 2   | N2   | null  |    | 2   | 200   | 
| 3   | N3   | 3     |    | 3   | 300   | 
| 4   | N4   | null  |    | 4   | 400   | 
| 5   | N5   | 2     |    | 5   | 500   | 
| 6   | N6   | 5     |    +-----+-------+
+-----+------+-------+
```

На запрос `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.t2_Id = t2.Id WHERE t1.Id < 5` мне вернётся следующая таблица

```
+-----------------------------------+
| result                            |
+-----+------+-------+------+-------+
| Id  | Name | t2_Id | Id1  | Val   | 
+-----+------+-------+------+-------+
| 1   | N1   | 1     | 1    | 100   | 
| 3   | N3   | 3     | 3    | 300   | 
+-----+------+-------+------+-------+
```

Какой запрос мне сделать, чтоб вернулась следующая таблица?

```
+-----------------------------------+
| result                            |
+-----+------+-------+------+-------+
| Id  | Name | t2_Id | Id1  | Val   | 
+-----+------+-------+------+-------+
| 1   | N1   | 1     | 1    | 100   | 
| 2   | N2   | null  | null | null  | 
| 3   | N3   | 3     | 3    | 300   | 
| 4   | N4   | null  | null | null  | 
+-----+------+-------+------+-------+
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` то что нужно

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin, то, что нужно. Можете оформить как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте в запросе `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.t2_Id = t2.Id
WHERE t1.Id < 5
```

[Ссылка на почитать о джойнах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))