# Join при определенном условии в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Изучаю MS SQL и застрял на одном моменте. У меня есть большое количество таблиц, среди них есть таблица "Object" с определенным ID, а в других таблицах есть внешние ключи "Object_ID", но при этом сторонние таблицы не обязательно должны иметь записи, ссылающиеся на "Object". Я хотел бы с помощью одного запроса получить **один** объект, который будет соединять в себе данные из всех таблиц по определенному "ID_Object", но если я просто сделаю для всех таблиц 
`Join таблица2 on Object.Object_ID = таблица2.ID_Object`,
то при отсутствии записи в "таблица2" с нужным "Object_ID" мне приходит пустой объект. В таком случае я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы *Join* просто не происходил.
Не мог бы мне кто-нибудь помочь?

Comment: почитайте про LEFT (RIGHT) JOIN, INNER JOIN и FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: [Здесь ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005817/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86)